# How can I write a shell extension for "Network Connections" for Windows 7 and later?

Tags: com, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I wanna extend the context menu like the one in the following picture. Is this doable?

I know a little about COM and shell extension, and I know what the "Network Connections" is in the shell namespace, but I don't know whether this one can be extended by shell extension or not.

Thanks 
[image: screenshot]